# Change page limit in test case

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework, django-testing

Question in short: how do I override the `PAGE_SIZE` setting of `REST_FRAMEWORK` in a test case in Django?

Details about question: I have the following settings in my project's `base.py`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'Masterdata.authentication.FashionExchangeAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}
```

Now I want to create a test case, in which I change the page size to 10. However, I cannot override this particular setting while keeping the rest of the dictionary intact. Does anyone know how to do so?

This is what I tried:

1) Adding the modify_settings decorator above the test method:

```
@modify_settings(REST_FRAMEWORK={
    'remove': 'PAGE_SIZE',
    'append': {'PAGE_SIZE': 10}
})
```

This does not change the setting.

2) Using override_settings as context manager:

```
test_settings = settings.REST_FRAMEWORK
test_settings['PAGE_SIZE'] = 10
with override_settings(REST_FRAMEWORK = test_settings):
    # do stuff
```

However, the line with `test_settings['PAGE_SIZE']=10` fails because apparently the variable `settings.REST_FRAMEWORK` is a list instead of a dictionary.

```
print(settings.REST_FRAMEWORK)

['DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES', 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES', 'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS', 'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS', 'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES']
```

How come this setting is a list here? I have verified that the variable is not overwritten anywhere else in the project.

Comment: why dont add another settings file for test?

Comment: in your settings you can create a condition by checking sys.argv. if sys.argv has 'test' in it then set PAGE_SIZE to 10

Answer (score -1):

Beneath your rest_framework settings, you can check for if this is test environment. This should work:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    REST_FRAMEWORK['PAGE_SIZE'] = 10
```

Otherwise you can create separate settings file for test cases:

```
# settings_tests.py
from settings import *

# Override your changes.
REST_FRAMEWORK['PAGE_SIZE'] = 10
```

Comment: But then it will be updated for *all* tests, not just for the method that I want.

Comment: You can run the test case for which you want different PAGE_SIZE by running "python manage.py test app.api.test.TestClass" and in your sys.argv you can check for if "app.api.test.TestClass" is present then set page size to 10 otherwise you will have to go for the simpler way, i.e. creating a seperate settings file for test cases